# Assign only one node of a struct to the same type of struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

Good day. I have a struct list, with the elements "name, available and *next". In the code below I am trying to get only one node (resource) into a list of the same struct. If I do this with the provided code, all the elements after that node (because of *next) are also put into the new list. Is there a way to take only the one node and put it into the new list?

```
struct resourceList *list = p->resourceListPtr;
    if (list == NULL) {
      list = resource;
      list->next = NULL;
      p->resourceListPtr = list;
}
```

The list->next = NULL, changes the resource->next to NULL as well. But how can I only change it for the second list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is: You can't.

If you want a "node" to be a member of two different lists, you have to design the list and node structures with that in mind from the beginning (for example by having separate structures for the data and the actual list nodes).

What you might be able to do is to *copy* the node from the existing list to the new list. That means you have to create a brand new `struct resourceList` node, copy it from `resource` and then add the new node to the list.

Perhaps something like

```
if (list == NULL)
{
    // Create a new node
    list = malloc(sizeof *list);

    // Copy the data from another node
    *list = *resource;

    // No nodes after this one
    list->next = NULL;

    // Make the new node the head of the list
    p->resourceListPtr = list;
}
```

<sub>[Error checking omitted]</sub>

---

If you want nodes in multiple lists to share data then you need to design the list with that in mind, as mentioned. One good way is to make separate structures for the list, the nodes and the data.

You could for example have something like

```
struct resource
{
    // The actual resource data
};

// Node in list
struct resourceNode
{
    struct resource *data;  // Pointer to the data
    struct resourceNode *next;  // Next node in list
};

struct resourceList
{
    struct resourceNode *head;
    struct resourceNode *tail;
};
```

With the above structures it's easy to have multiple lists with unique nodes, but where the data in the node could be shared between list.

Simple example:

```
// Create two lists
struct resourceList list1;
struct resourceList list2;
// TODO: Initialization of the lists

struct resource my_resource;
// TODO: Initialization of my_resource ...

// Add the same resource to both lists
resource_list_add(&list1, &my_resource);
resource_list_add(&list2, &my_resource);
```

If you change the resource data, it will be changed for both list.

It is also easy to add the data from one list into another list:

```
struct resourceNode *node1 = list1.head;
resource_list_add(&list2, node1->data);
```

Comment: `list = malloc(struct resourceList);` might need a bit of editing. :)

Comment: If I were to change list->available, the resource->available doesn't change. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @RikusStrydom Not with my example code, since it creates a brand new and distinct copy of the node. The two nodes are not related. If you want to have nodes in multiple lists to share data, you need to keep the data separate from the node.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a node, you have to copy the memory used by it, into newly allocated memory.

Something like:

```
if (list == NULL)
{
  list = malloc(sizeof *list);
  if (list != NULL)
  {
    *list = *resource;
    list->next = NULL;
    p->resourceListPtr = list;
  }
}
```